# Populating a TreeView from a query

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tree, treeview, treenode

I'm trying to populate a C# tree view from a database query.

The database is structured something like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------
| PARENT_NODE | CHILD_NODE | LEVEL | NAME     |
-----------------------------------------------
|     1       |     2      |   1   | name1    |
-----------------------------------------------
|     1       |     4      |   1   | name2    |
-----------------------------------------------
|     2       |     6      |   1   | name4    |
-----------------------------------------------
|     2       |     3      |   2   | name3    |
-----------------------------------------------
|     3       |   null     |   3   | name5    |
-----------------------------------------------
```

Note the databse query cannot be changed.

And as a representation of the tree view it would look something like this.

```
name1
  |---- name3
  |       |---- name5
name2
  |
  |
name4
```

I have tried to look for others having similar problems as I do. However, the examples have been tricky to follow and usually doesn't work for me. Either I implemented it wrong or it just doesn't work for my situation.

My latest try was to make a loop within a loop to iterate through the children and try to associate them with the parents. But it didn't show anything instead.

```
// Nodes
            TreeNode rootNode = new TreeNode("root_NAME");
            TreeNode parent = new TreeNode();
            TreeNode child = new TreeNode();


            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                if (dr["LEVEL"].ToString() == "1")
                {
                    parent = new TreeNode(dr["NAME"].ToString());
                    rootNode.Nodes.Add(parent);
                    //TreeView.traceTreeView.Nodes.Add(node);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Search for where child_node == parent_node and add that node 

                    List<TreeNode> childList = new List<TreeNode>();


                    foreach (DataRow cr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        if (cr["PARENT_NODE"].ToString() == dr["CHILD_NODE"].ToString())
                        {
                            childList.Add(child = new TreeNode(cr["NAME"].ToString()));
                        }
                    }
                    TreeNode[] childArray = childList.ToArray();

                    TreeNode node = new TreeNode(dr["NAME"].ToString(), childArray);
                    parent.Nodes.Add(node);

                }

            }
```

Would someone tell/show me how I can iterate through a table and associate parent and child nodes and then add them to the treeview?

Comment: not an answer but i think looking up `AVL trees` might help.

Comment: Which node does `NAME` refer to? The parent node or the child node? It seems to vary based on your sample data. `LEVEL` also makes no sense as `name1` and `name2` have the same level but you're saying they should be nested.

Comment: I don't think Forms Tree is was you think it is. I actually don't really understand what you're trying to display based on your representation.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Every node has their own name, both child and parent. Name1 and Name2 are in fact a child of a root node whereby there is a level0. However this level is not construced in the query.

Comment: @VinnieNovido then I don't understand your graph. I thought name2 was supposed to be a child of name1, but if you say they're both children of a level 0, then why is name4 drawn in the same way as name2 ?

Comment: @Kilazur I do know what I want. I might not be the best at showing it. It should look like this: [link](http://csharp.net-informations.com/xml/img/xml-tree.JPG)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Ah! You are correct. I have misprinted the structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below I'll present how I solved this.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            if (!UserFunctions.IsNullOrEmpty(traceWindow.traceTreeView.Nodes.Find(dr["PARENT_NODE"].ToString(), true)))
            {
                // add child to parent
                // if child_node == null -> cNode.Name(Text) = "INDATA"
                TreeNode cNode;
                // "JOB_NAME_IN" is a column name in the database
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["JOB_NAME_IN"].ToString()))
                {
                    cNode = new TreeNode(dr["JOB_NAME_IN"].ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    cNode = new TreeNode(dr["INDATA"].ToString());
                }
                // .Name is the key of that node. 
                // Setting it to child node allows me to search for which node is the parent of the current datarow i'm reading.
                cNode.Name = dr["CHILD_NODE"].ToString();
                TreeNode[] pNode = traceWindow.traceTreeView.Nodes.Find(dr["PARENT_NODE"].ToString(), true);

                pNode[0].Nodes.Add(cNode);

            }
            else
            {
                // There is no child, create new parent
                // if child_node == null -> cNode.Name(Text) = "INDATA"
                TreeNode pNode;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["JOB_NAME_IN"].ToString()))
                {
                    pNode = new TreeNode(dr["JOB_NAME_IN"].ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    pNode = new TreeNode(dr["INDATA"].ToString());
                }
                pNode.Name = dr["CHILD_NODE"].ToString(); // Key
                traceWindow.traceTreeView.Nodes.Add(pNode);
            }


        }
```

Note that I have created an extended method of `IsNullOrEmpty` It looks like follows:

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this Array array)
    {
        // This is an extension of an existing function
        // to make it work with arrays.

        return (array == null || array.Length == 0);
    }
```